# Unable to create a simple latex 4x4 table on a half page using tabular

Tags: tables

I've spent over an hour trying to create a simple 4x3 table on latex. Nothing fancy, jus what I'd have done with word. Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{\textbf{some caption}}
    
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    
    \textbf{Test (µm)} & \textbf{ (Some really really really long name )} & \textbf{Name name mname} & \textbf{more name)} \\
   \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
   \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
      \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
         \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

unfortunately, the table keeps overflowing and gets missing as you can see from the screenshot below:

[image]

I'd really appreaciate advice about how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid the use of `H` for placement. If you don't want the table to float, then don't make it a float by removing the `table` environment.

If you don't instruct LaTeX that line breaks are possible, then it's normal that columns become too wide. Use a `p`-type column. For example:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = fr_FR

\documentclass[science]{titiarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \caption{\textbf{some caption}}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|l|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Test (µm)} & \textbf{ (Some really really really long name )} & \textbf{Name name mname} & \textbf{more name)} \\
    \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you want more flexibility or other controls, you should use the more modern `tabularray` package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow (more or less) automatic line breaking in the header cells. However, the basic column types `l`, `c`, and `r` do not allow automatic line breaking.

There are many ways to allow line breaking in LaTeX tables.. One such way is to load the tabularx package and employ the `tabularx` environment and the `X` column type. In the following solution, columns 2 thru 4 employ (a modified form of) the `X` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for tabularx env. and X column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for \RaggedRight macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % ragged-right

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Some caption\strut}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|L|L|L|}
\hline
Test (µm) & (Some really really really long name) & Name name name & more name \\
\hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```